# What could be a reason for this WiFi signal pattern?

Tags: wireless-networking

Not sure if that's the right forum, but hope someone can help:

[image: inSSIDer screenshot]

This happens on any channel.
Usually there are many more networks visible as well.

Comment: The dropouts stopped for all wifi connected clients simultaneously, but ping pattern is still persistent. http://cl.ly/0O0Y3i1O1F3J0H0B3D42

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean the dropout? I'm not an expert, but you might be getting a ["picket fence"](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KmxSImzceRAJ:engweb.info/courses/wdt/lecture04/WIMAX_Technology_r.html+picket+fence+wifi+signal&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) effect. Are you near the transmitter when you get these readings? If you don't get a decent answer here, you may want to check on something like a ham radio forum for signal analysis.

> Multipath Interference
>   Multipath Interference (sometimes called picket fencing or flutter) happens when wireless signals bounce around between obstructions that lie between the transmitter and receiver. There may be a direct path between the transmitter and receiver and a secondary path. This secondary path will be a longer path and therefore a percentage of the power of the original signal will arrive later than the signal that travelled via the direct path.
>
> It is possible that there will be a few microseconds of delay between the signal arriving by direct path and the signal that has taken a longer path. This can limit data rate and also limits the area of coverage of any transmitter.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The issue is that this is a stationary computer and it was working almost perfectly up until now. There were no changes in furniture, or other possible interference sources. I have extended the antenna to a different location/direction, and now have mostly stable signal, but something is still very weird with ping: http://cl.ly/0O0Y3i1O1F3J0H0B3D42

Comment: +1 for "check with some radio people".  Is there a radio.SE?

Comment: @Shinrai I think they're still trying to get one launched in area51.

Comment: @Unirgy Not sure, could be that a neighbor moved something that's reflecting signals, or you have some kind of interference across the band (say like a Microwave) or even something as simple as failing hardware. Again, someone more experienced with radio signals might recognize the pattern more readily. It looks like a fairly regular pattern.